# How to parse an Xml which contains the field with an new line using java parsers

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax, jdom

How to parse an Xml which contains the field with an new line as it is using java parsers.

```xml
<ThreeDSecure>
   <acs_url>https://nithesh/testing</acs_url>
   <pareq_message>
    dfsgndfisfgsdgsdgsfggsfgsdfgs
    rfk/ffsgsdgfdssg32afaaaaffasa
    sgsdgsdfgsdfgfg
    ssdgfsgs342;dhhdgssssregs
    sffsgsdgfdssgsfregssdgsdg54df
    fdgdfgdfg
   </pareq_message>
</ThreeDSecure>
```

Here i need to read pareq_message tag value as it is, help me to resolve this. i have used the Xml parsers to read the fields, BUT i'm getting as an String with one line.

```java
if("pareq_message".equals(sThreeDSecure)){
    String sPareqMessage =threeDSecureCursor.collectDescendantText();
    objNBGIBankResponseBean.setPareqMessage(sPareqMessage);
} //if closed (PareqMessage)
```

Comment: The XML parser may return just a single string, but that string is still multi-line, with embedded newlines. It may be your way of showing the string that ignores newlines.

Comment: Yes GPI, im using StaxMate Parser

Comment: @forty-two you are right. I got confused. I will delete my comment so that future readers are not mislead.

Comment: @forty-two May i know alternate solution to get string as it is

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML library to read the text with newline

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
var message = xdoc.Descendants("pareq_message").First();
var value = message.Value;
```

This should work.